# Define a perl variable inside AWK statement

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

I have defined a perl variable inside the awk script.

```
my $max = 76500;
my $uidNumber = `ypcat passwd | cut -d ":" -f3 | awk -v var=\$max '\$NF >= 76000 && \$NF <= \{print var\}' | sort -n`;
print $uidNumber
```

I get below error when I run the script

```
awk: $NF >= 76000 && $NF <= {print var}
awk:                        ^ syntax error
```

Works perfectly when the varible is not defined

```
my $uidNumber = `ypcat passwd | cut -d ":" -f3 | awk '\$NF >= 76000 && \$NF <= 76500' | sort -n`;
print $uidNumber
```

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this? Execcing `cat/cut/awk/sort` from perl is redundant? Could you explain what you're trying to get out of your `/etc/passwd` ? Looking at it, all UIDs between 7600 and 76500?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so my first answer would be: Don't.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $passwd_file, '<', 'passwd' ) or die $!; 

while ( <$passwd_file> ) { 
    chomp;
    my ( $username, $x, $uid, @rest ) = split /:/;
    print $uid,"\n" if $uid >= 76000 and $uid <= 76500;
}
```

That's not sorted, it's just in 'passwd file' order it'll print. I'm not clear what you're actually looking for, because you sort at the end - so will have a string with a load of numbers in it.

But maybe something like this is what you'd want?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


open ( my $passwd_file, '<', 'passwd' ) or die $!; 

my @uids; 
while ( <$passwd_file> ) { 
    chomp;
    my ( $username, $x, $uid, @rest ) = split /:/;
    push ( @uids, $uid ) if $uid <=76500 and $uid >= 76000; 
}

print join "\n", sort { $a <=> $b } @uids;
```

Note - as you mention in the comments it's a ypcat command:

```
open ( my $input, '-|', 'ypcat passwd' );
```

And then do the same thing.

Sorting the list and printing last element:

```
print "UID:", (sort { $a <=> $b } @uids )[-1],"\n";
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's not a file i'm reading from. its the `ypcat` command in NIS. I've updated question above.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example?

Comment: See last line of answer :)

Comment: Thanks, One more thing i want to sort and print the last element of the array - `@uids`, can you update that too.

Comment: OK... but that shouldn't be too horrific to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
my $uidNumber = `ypcat passwd | cut -d ":" -f3 | awk '\$NF >= 76000 && \$NF <= $max' | sort -n`;
```

But you're writing a Perl program, and it would be far better to do this in Perl, or even as a single awk command

```
my $max = 76_500;

my @uids = do {
    open my $fh, '-|', 'ypcat passwd' or die $!;
    sort { $a <=> $b } grep { $_ >= 76_000 and $_ <= $max } map { (split /:/)[2] } <$fh>;
};
```

Your use of a scalar `$uidNumber` implies that you expect to find only a single UID in that range, but your use of `sort` says that you expect many. If you want multiple UIDs in one string, each followed by a newline then you can now say

```
my  $uidNumber = join "", map "$_\n", @uids;
```

but it seems more useful to keep the UIDs in an array